# How do I access instance of fragment using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

When injecting into a fragment using     `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`, How do I access that fragment instance in a module? I am trying to inject Androids NavController class but I need an instance of either an activity or fragment. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ContributesAndroidInjector you should be able to access to the Fragment instance through any modules included in the generated Subcomponent.

e.g.

```
@Module
abstract class MyContributesModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyFragmentModule::class])
    internal abstract fun myFragment(): MyFragment
}

@Module
abstract class MyFragmentModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun myFragmentInteractor(myFragmentInteractorImpl: MyFragmentInteractorImpl): MyFragmentInteractor
}

interface MyFragmentInteractor {
    fun doSomething()
}

class MyFragmentInteractorImpl @Inject constructor(private val myFragment : MyFragment) : MyFragmentInteractor {
    override fun doSomething() {
        // doSomething with myFragment
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var interactor: MyFragmentInteractor

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
```